# From win32 color Code to set Element BackColor in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have XML file where Elements Back color is available in node where node's color value is stored in form of Win32 color value. Now want to convert this value to Hex value so that i can use it in jQuery as CSS property.

Example is below

```
<INPUTBACKCOLOR>33023</INPUTBACKCOLOR>
```

Change it to

```
 $("elemet").css('background-color',"#SomeHexValueFromINPUTBACKCOLORNode")
```

How can i do this?

Comment: By "Win32 color value", do you mean a `COLORREF`? In other words, does the color `33023` result in pure orange?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes it is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source color is stored in a [COLORREF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449.aspx), so its structure is in the form `0x00bbggrr` (in hexadecimal).

Therefore, to convert it to its CSS representation, you have to:

- Convert the value to a hexadecimal string,
- Pad the hex string with zeroes on the left side,
- Swap the red and blue channels,
- Prepend a hash sign `#`.

Which can be achieved with something like:

```
var cssColor = "000000" + parseInt(sourceColor, 10).toString(16);
cssColor = cssColor.substr(cssColor.length - 6);
cssColor = "#" + cssColor.substr(4, 2) + cssColor.substr(2, 2)
    + cssColor.substr(0, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks For your Answer. I have tried this in my Web page but its not showing Correct Color. this Color is Orange but it shows diffrent Color. Other Elements had White Color as BackColor and it shows some diffrent color. White Color code is 16777215.

Comment: Strange, it does work for me (I created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rnxjvLeh/) to demonstrate).

Comment: I have updated fiddle example please check its not coming correct color value. I just wondering why its not coming Correct values. if you pass direct value its working fine but if you take that value from somewhere then its giving problem.

Comment: Well, your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnxjvLeh/1/) also works for me -- the background of the text box does remain white when the source color value is `16777215`, as it should...

Comment: Sorry i forgot to share you link Here is a link to check  http://jsfiddle.net/rnxjvLeh/8/

Comment: There are two issues in that fiddle. First, you should acquire the textbox's value with `$("#color").val()`, not `$("#color").text()`. Second, since your source color is a string, `toString(16)` will not work properly. You would have to parse the source value into a number beforehand. I updated my answer (and [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnxjvLeh/9/)) in that direction.

Comment: Thanks For Your answer i just wondering why its not coming. Now my dought is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
color = 33023;
r = color & 0x000000FF;
g = ( color & 0x0000FF00 ) >> 8;
b = ( color & 0x00FF0000 ) >> 16;

alert(r+" "+g+" "+b);
```

It converts the color to rgb, now you can convert it to hex or can use the rgb() expression.

[Source](http://www.alteridem.net/2007/08/23/win32-colorref-vs-net-color/)

```
function getColor(color)
{
    r = color & 0x000000FF;
    g = ( color & 0x0000FF00 ) >> 8;
    b = ( color & 0x00FF0000 ) >> 16;
    return "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
}

function getColorAndAlpha(color)
{
    r = color & 0x000000FF;
    g = ( color & 0x0000FF00 ) >> 8;
    b = ( color & 0x00FF0000 ) >> 16;
    a = ( color & 0xFF000000 ) >> 24;
    return "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+","+a+")";
}
```